# Are there group permissions for django-rosetta?

Tags: django

Is there an opportunity to have permission groups for django-rosetta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do fine-grained permissions, but it looks like you [can control who can contribute translations using a group named 'translators'](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta#security).